# Is it bad to answer a question if I will be incrementally working on it, or do I present a finished product in the beginning?

Tags: discussion

I thought I'd share this recent situation I *just* faced, not in the spirit of criticism or rant... but just to share my feelings.

There was a question that I was interested in answering. It was something like "How do I make specific loops in this Java code"

Now, like other users, I'm about those points. I won't lie - I *do* want to be the first answer.

So I add some preliminary work , code and click submit.

Instantly I get :

```
D00d,where's your code formatting?
```

Fair enough, I guess. But I'm a little miffed. I would think that the user understands that I, also, have eyes and can see. And that with my above-average badge display I know the system.

So I fix that and move on.

But it doesn't stop. As I'm working on my answer, I'm getting downvoted. I *know* that I need to adapt this code, I *know* that it's not yet fully an answer...

Eventually, I have -3. I delete my own answer then.
But it feels bad to have worked on something, then to abandon it.
Well, it is what is I guesss.

thanks for reading

Comment: Unquestionably; post a fully formed answer whenever possible.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Fair enough, I guess. But I'm a little miffed. I would think that the
>   user understands that I, also, have eyes and can see. And that with my
>   above-average badge display I know the system.

Then with your veteran experience you should be aware of the [Fastest Gun in the West problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem) and why posting incomplete answers is frowned upon. It only indicates to others that you want to call "dibs" on the reputation by being the first to answer, which is further indicated by your comment:

> Now, like other users, I'm about those points. I won't lie - I do want
>   to be the first answer.

The problem is further exacerbated if the question is a rather trivial one. A trivial question that doesn't require an elaborate answer takes even less effort to answer, which reflects badly if you can't even be bothered to format your post correctly before hitting submit. Sometimes this can work in your favor, other times it doesn't (as the downvotes show.)

After revising your post, you may ping the users to let them know that you have done so. They may reverse their downvote or even turn it into an upvote. Not everyone on this site is an evil downvoter.

Comment: Voting as best phrase of the year: `Not everyone on this site is an evil downvoter.`

Answer (score 17):

Sounds like you're trying to be a [Fastest Gun in the West](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem). People are going to evaluate your post based on how it appears when they see it. If you want to avoid getting downvoted for works-in-progress, simply don't post until it's presentable.

Answer (score 0):

When answering a question, I usually try to provide a detailed answer that will leave the OP and anyone else who comes along without additional questions ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24226795/select-case-statement-working-with-variables-vb-net/)). Sometimes that takes a lot of typing and I'm not always the first person to post an answer or comment to a question ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24267030/get-files-with-multiple-extensions-and-adding-them-to-listbox/)). I'll admit that strategy isn't the fastest way to fill up the rep meter. However if I put myself in the shoes of the people reading my answer, I would rather read a well put together answer that has all the info in it I need to understand whats going on than to read a hastily posted slopjob ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24272276/do-not-require-attention-for-showdialog/)).